# Not able to load a network graph of 45000 nodes on gephi

Tags: graph, gephi

I am trying to load a network graph on gephi of 45000 nodes.The Application stops and asks me save the current file in .gephi format .But when I try to load the file it gives me an xml parse error.

Answer (score 2):

I've done larger Graphs without problem. Allow more memory to gephi, as described in https://gephi.org/users/install/

Comment: changed the config file after posting the question.But still pretty damn slow must be my system or some other issue .thanks

Comment: I am somehow unable to change my gephi.conf file. Whenever I save the file after increasing the memory, it says 'access denied'. Any ideas on how to increase the memory?

Comment: @Patthebug probably, you're trying to edit conf. file in Program Files directory, which require administrative access rights. To solve the problem, you can open a file in editor with administrative privileges. Or just copy the file outside of Program Files, then make some changes and copy it back, replacing old one.